# Place of definition of the autogenerated relation methods in Loopback 3.x

Tags: javascript, json, frameworks, loopback

I want to know where the autogenerated code is for the relation between two models in Loopback.

I don't know where I can find this code.

From the documentation of Loopback:

> For example, if a User hasMany projects, LoopBack creates these routes
>   (among others) and the corresponding related model methods:

```
/api/users/count - standard method is count
/api/users/:id/projects - related model method is __get__projects
/api/users/:id/projects/count - related model method is __count__projects
```

I expect the folder of the original definition for that method.

Answer (score 0):

Relation methods like `__get_projects__` are defined in two places in LoopBack 3.

1. Remoting metadata is contributed by `loopback` module, see [lib/model.js](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/3a2a645e0ce0fbd19106265373a1a66df00fb64d/lib/model.js#L546-L863).
2. The actual implementation of these remote methods comes from `loopback-datasource-juggler`.

   In particular, the double-underscore methods for HasMany relation are implemented in [lib/relation-definition.js#L726-L758](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/47addd943adfd7ace37cd52d2d4dcbd04ee7c0d8/lib/relation-definition.js#L726-L758).

   Check the rest of that file to find implementation of other methods and relation types (e.g. BelongsTo).